# How to load an XML/HTML resource in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, junit, playframework, junit4

I'm working with Play Framework 2.0. In one of my test cases I want to read the content of some XML/HTML files. I've tried with:

```
getClass().getResource("SomeFile.xml");
```

and

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("SomeFile.xml");
```

But I get a null. The resources are in the same package of my test case.[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a resource stream from the classpath.
 *
 * @param relativePath relative path of the resource to fetch
 * @return InputStream to the resource (may be null)
 */
play.Play.application().resourceAsStream(String resourceName)
```